# How to use Icon Toggle button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use Icon button in Jetpack Compose, but I couldn't understand Jetpack Compose docs. Can someone share a sample code for toggle button similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T4pn.gif)?
When user clicks on a button, I want to animate it like in Instagram with a bounce animation.

Comment: There is a great video on how to implement that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5C3P7VWW5k

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine [IconToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#IconToggleButton(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)) with transitions. Sample code (using version 1.0.0-beta05):

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColor
import androidx.compose.animation.core.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@SuppressLint("UnusedTransitionTargetStateParameter")
@Composable
fun FavoriteButton(
    isChecked: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isChecked,
        onCheckedChange = { onClick() }
    ) {
        val transition = updateTransition(isChecked, label = "Checked indicator")

        val tint by transition.animateColor(
            label = "Tint"
        ) { isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) Color.Red else Color.Black
        }

        val size by transition.animateDp(
            transitionSpec = {
                if (false isTransitioningTo true) {
                    keyframes {
                        durationMillis = 250
                        30.dp at 0 with LinearOutSlowInEasing // for 0-15 ms
                        35.dp at 15 with FastOutLinearInEasing // for 15-75 ms
                        40.dp at 75 // ms
                        35.dp at 150 // ms
                    }
                } else {
                    spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessVeryLow)
                }
            },
            label = "Size"
        ) { 30.dp }

        Icon(
            imageVector = if (isChecked) Icons.Filled.Favorite else Icons.Filled.FavoriteBorder,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = tint,
            modifier = Modifier.size(size)
        )
    }
}

@Preview("Favorite Button")
@Composable
fun FavoriteButtonPreview() {
    val (isChecked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface {
            FavoriteButton(
                isChecked = isChecked, 
                onClick = { setChecked(!isChecked) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

These are the required dependencies for this sample:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0-alpha01'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta05"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta05"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta05"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'
}
```

For more details about `transition` and `keyframes` and ways to customize them, see Compose's [Animation documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation).

Comment: Sorry but its give this errors
Unresolved reference: animateColor
Unresolved reference: tooling
Unresolved reference: updateTransition
Unresolved reference: isTransitioningTo

public fun Icon(asset: ImageAsset, modifier: Modifier = ..., tint: Color = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material
public fun Icon(painter: Painter, modifier: Modifier = ..., tint: Color = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material
public fun Icon(asset: VectorAsset, modifier: Modifier = ..., tint: Color = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I added the required dependencies to the answer. Also, make sure you're copying the various `import` statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Switch:

```
var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Switch(
  modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Demo" },
  checked = checked,
  onCheckedChange = { checked = it }
)
```

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Switch(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.SwitchColors,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea to use [Chips](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/guidelines) instead.

> Filter chips use tags or descriptive words to filter content. They can be a good alternative to toggle buttons or checkboxes.

Also it's possible to use `Modifier.selectable`.